# Element uninitialized in javascript/Html when it should be

Tags: javascript, html

Bellow is my code snippet that present the problem what I'm facing with:

```
<!-- in a div -->
<a href="#" onclick="submit('/netnfork/site/billing/billing_plan_type', document.getElementById('dataForm'));" title="${addPlan}">
    <img src="/path/to/button" height="18" width="25" class="add_button"/>
</a>

<!-- bellow this, in another div -->
<form id="dataForm" action="/a/path" method="post">     
    <input type="hidden" name="page_number" id="pageNumber" value="//some JSP code"/>     
    <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="rowId" />        
</form>
```

the submit function is declared in another file that is included in the beginning of this html file.

The problem is, that when I click on the link, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of null`. Trying to alert the second parameter of submit function, I get `null`.

```
function submit(url, form) {
    alert(form);
    form.action = url;
    form.submit();  
}
```

I have an exact similar page in the same application that is working good. Can anyone explain me why I get this behavior?

*I ran this page in Chrome and Mozilla, but the error occurs in both of them.*

Comment: I tested your code in jsfiddle and it working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/Myhw3/1/.

Comment: @artaxerxe I tried this it's working fine  http://jsfiddle.net/cxVEJ/8/ .

Comment: @Shusl I also have the same code (just a little bit different) in other page, and it works fine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that this (specifically `getElementById`):

```
submit('/netnfork/site/billing/billing_plan_type', document.getElementById('dataForm'));
```

gets evaluated before the `form` actually exists in the `DOM`, to fix the problem you will need to change it to the following:

```
function submit(url, formName) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formName);
    form.action = url;
    form.submit();
}
```

and in your `HTML`:

```
submit('/netnfork/site/billing/billing_plan_type', 'dataForm');
```

Alternatively you should use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to handle this sort of functionality

Comment: Even with your suggestion, error is the same. I also put the form before of link (<a>) element, but the error persists.

Comment: the only other possibility is that there are multiple elements with the same `id` on your page then. Can you post an example for us to re-create?

Comment: I found the solution, trying to put a simplified form of my html file, at your suggestion. That's why I accepted your answer. :). Thanks.

Comment: Happened to me before as well, sometimes you get the answer by just trying to shorten your own code for an example :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: above the code presented I had a div like this:

`<form action="#" method="post" id="submenuForm" />`.

I just put this instead:

`<form action="#" method="post" id="submenuForm" > </form>`, and now works good.